# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Gallery.Server.dll is missing when Upgrade DevOps 2022p4 to 2022 0.1

Tags: azure-devops-server-2022

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Gallery.Server.dll is missing when Upgrade of Azure DevOps 2022p4 to 2022 0.1 into same directory is executed. I tried this 3 times and always the same issue. Installing just 2022 0.1 on a clean machine is fine.

When this file is missing database upgrade will fail after some database upgrade steps are completed.
The database is corrupt after this failure.

The readiness check is not checking this missing file (or any other might be also missing).

Any fix for this? How can I upgrade on this error from 2022 to 2022 0.1 best way? Install on a clean machine and copy/paste this file before running the configuration assistent after installation?

[image: Error message]

```
TF255356: The following error occurred when configuring the Azure DevOps databases: TF400711: Error
occurred while executing servicing step 'Install Inherited Service Definitions' for component
InstallInheritedDefinitionsOnPrem during StartlnstallHostUpdates: Could not load file or assembly
'Microsoft.VisualStud10.Services.Gallery.Server, Version: 19.0.0.0, Culture: neutral,
PublicKeyToken= b03f5f7f11 d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..
For more informatiorv see the configuration log.
```

[image: Directory compare]

Comment: Contact Microsoft Support: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511 or submit your issue on the developer community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOpsServerTFS

You could always try pasting in the file from before the upgrade.

Comment: Or use the one from a clean upgrade.

Comment: thanks - done -> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MicrosoftVisualStudioServicesGallery/10458410

Comment: Looks like they came back with a workaround.